# Google Sheets CountIf Two Columns

Tags: google-sheets-api

countif command with two sections and have it get the total number of entries on a spreadsheet with one column having say a work "Pediatrics" and the second column having "infant"

Comment: what about using countif separately and later merge them into one column

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Given a spreadsheet similar to

[image]

Use the Countifs function

```
=COUNTIFS(C3:C11,"Infant",D3:D11,"Pediatrics")
```